# "sudo apt-get update" error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

When I enter in terminal `sudo apt-get update` I get this error below. 
Any ideas on how to resolve it?

```
Fetched 306 kB in 9s (31.7 kB/s)                                               
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: The PPA you've added, ppa:relan/exfat, doesn't seem to exist. Remove it with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:relan/exfat`.

Comment: @mikewhatever The PPA exists but has nothing for xenial and last update was in 2014. And not needed because the exFAT support and tools are in the repositories.

Comment: did the purge but still coming up with the warning. I guess it not a huge issue `$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:relan/exfat
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`

Comment: you could try `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` find the line containing the repo and delete it manually. If there is no line check if there is a file with according name somewhere in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (on Ubuntu 16.04):

In the desktop GUI software center updater, go to other software tab and uncheck

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/relan/exfat/ubuntu xenial main
```

What I think occurred: I ran `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat utils` without prefacing that with an `apt-get update` first and then an `apt-get upgrade`. The system was freshly installed and I wanted to jump right into formatting an SD-card!